# Combining color hex blending algorithm with standard CMYK colored buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, algorithm, hex

I am trying to blend any combination of colors using colored buttons which output a specific hex number in combination with a slider bar from bootstrap that allows the user to indicate the percentage of color they want to use.

I couldn't get the slider to properly run and I'm not sure why.

I do need some help combining the pieces of code into a working algorithm that I can use for my art class. The full code can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mw7optL5/289/

```
//Hex blending algorithm
var mix = function(color_1, color_2, weight) {
  function d2h(d) { return d.toString(16); }  // convert a decimal value to hex
  function h2d(h) { return parseInt(h, 16); } // convert a hex value to decimal 

  weight = (typeof(weight) !== 'undefined') ? weight : 50; // set the weight to 50%, if that argument is omitted

  var color = "#";

  for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i += 2) { // loop through each of the 3 hex pairs—red, green, and blue
    var v1 = h2d(color_1.substr(i, 2)), // extract the current pairs
        v2 = h2d(color_2.substr(i, 2)),

        // combine the current pairs from each source color, according to the specified weight
        val = d2h(Math.floor(v2 + (v1 - v2) * (weight / 100.0))); 

    while(val.length < 2) { val = '0' + val; } // prepend a '0' if val results in a single digit

    color += val; // concatenate val to our new color string
  }

  return color; // PROFIT!
  };

//buttons
 <button class="Yellow" onclick="mix('#ffff00')">Yellow</button>
 <button class="Magenta" onclick="mix('#D9017A')">Magenta</button>
 <button class="Cyan" onclick="mix('#009FDF')">Cyan</button>
 <button class="Black" onclick="mix('#2D2926')">Black</button>
 <button class="Orange021" onclick="mix('#FE5000')">Orange</button>

//slider bar
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>

var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});
```

Comment: You're calling `mix` always with one parameter, but it should be called with at least 2 parameters. I don't see any variable that will store current value of slider (even scale from 0 to 20 is not clear ).

Comment: I fixed your jsfiddle to display at least that slider https://jsfiddle.net/mw7optL5/298/ . You need to load jquery **before** bootstrap's sources. I moved also document background color assignment to function. `color` is defined is scope of `mix` function you can't access it outside in this way.

Answer (score 3):

This just solves the mechanics I think you want (run and save the slider value properly), and it could be used as starter point. This doesn't solve the formula of **any combination of colors** as you want.

- Create an object based in the buttons with all percentages (0 default) like  `{ Yellow: 0, Magenta: 0, Cyan: 0, Black: 0 }`
- Add an event listener to each button `.click` (jquery) or `.addEventListener` (pure js)
- In the callback of each button, save the color and percentage into the object, like `colorPercentages[colors[i].getAttribute("id")] = $("#ex1").val();`  where `$("#ex1").val()` is the slider's value.
- Draw the color based in some formula, like `$("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')');`

In this case I've used this formula:

**Red = 255 x ( 1 - Cyan / 100 ) x ( 1 - Black / 100 )**

**Green = 255 x ( 1 - Magenta / 100 ) x ( 1 - Black / 100 )**

**Blue = 255 x ( 1 - Yellow / 100 ) x ( 1 - Black / 100 )**

Here a full functional example based on @barbsan modifications: https://jsfiddle.net/5dsgbne9/

That example is using the color button click event, but you could use the inverse logic as well, changing the color when user moves the slider with something like:

```
$("#ex1").slider().on('slideStop', function(ev){
    //code
});
```

As I understand, a blending algorithm it's pretty difficult to achieve, this question and the answers give some good approaches: [Mixing two colors "naturally" in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819058/mixing-two-colors-naturally-in-javascript), but you still need to mix n colors, not just 2, which is even more complex. Fortunately it seems to be not impossible.

Comment: Heres one example that does something similar. https://www.goldenpaints.com/mixer

Comment: @ssj3goku878 I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819058/mixing-two-colors-naturally-in-javascript that is a good approach I think. I've made some test in goldenpaints and they use an API, the good new is that its backend have Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* header so we can use it. The bad is that they pass the color as paintId and thats is not n color.