# D3.js generate a color proportional to the values of a key

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a Tree data structure where each non-leaf node (children) have this object:

```
    mime_types={
  "application/octet-stream": 1,
  "application/x-executable": 49,
  "application/x-object": 13,
  "application/x-sharedlib": 47,
  "image/gif": 5,
  "image/png": 3,
  "inode/symlink": 4,
  "text/plain": 58
}
```

Each leaf of my tree have a single type and its relative color (for example, a text/plain leaf will be colored blue). I implemented it doing:

```
var ListMimes = ['text/plain', 'application/x-executable', 'application/x-sharedlib', 'application/x-object', 'image/gif', 'inode/symlink', 'image/png', 'application/octet-stream']

var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(ListMimes).range(d3.schemeSet3);
```

**But for each non-leaf node, i want to color it (i'm drawing a sunburst) in a **"proportional"** way.** I try to explain better:
In this example i have *text/plain* with value 58, so this will "weight" much more than *application/octet-stream* in the result of the final color. So if text/plain is blue, and application/octet-stream is green, the final color will be blue with a very very little quantity of green

How can i do it using d3?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819058/mixing-two-colors-naturally-in-javascript